# Removing selected classes from html

Tags: jquery, html, removeclass

I want load html code with jQuery and delete from this code some classes, my code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="new-nav"></div>
      <script>
         $("#new-nav").load("/php/grab.php");

      </script>
      <script>
         $('.main_title_news_submain_block').remove();
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

is problem that .remove function not working, I dont know why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to perform the `.remove()` after the content is loaded using the callback function.

```
$("#new-nav").load("/php/grab.php", function(){
    /*removes the element with class main_title_news_submain_block*/
    $('.main_title_news_submain_block').remove();
});
```

Edit:
You might also wrap everything in a document ready to ensure the load is occurring after the element with the id new-nav is loaded in the dom.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#new-nav").load("/php/grab.php", function(){
        /*removes the element with class main_title_news_submain_block*/
        $('.main_title_news_submain_block').remove(); 
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't know why, but class is still removed ;(

Comment: @TomasLietuva - what do you mean "class is still removed"? What are you trying to accomplish? Removing the class or the element attached to the class?

Comment: No sorry, class is still displayed.

Comment: Could you provide the html that is being added to the new-nav element? Are you certain there is an element with the class main_title_news_submain_block in that html?

Comment: Yes, `< div id new-nav><div class="head"><div class="body"><div class="main_title_news_submain_block"></div></div></div></div>`

Answer (score 3):

Wrap it inside `document.ready` If that html element is after page load.

```
$(function () {
   $('.main_title_news_submain_block').remove();
});
```

If it loaded using `.load` then add it to the callback.

```
$("#new-nav").load("/php/grab.php", function () {
   $('.main_title_news_submain_block').remove();
});
```

Comment: I not understand how code must look, write only second script or what ?

Comment: @TomasLietuva I think so.. but before that please try to understand how and why you are doing this.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try it on the **callback** of your [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method ?

```
  $(function(){
      $("#new-nav").load("/php/grab.php",function(){ 
         $('.main_title_news_submain_block').remove();              
      });
  });
```

> If a "complete" callback is provided, it is executed after
>   post-processing and HTML insertion has been performed.

So the line with `remove()` method will be executed after the load function loads the content to the specified div in the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

I see you are not using the DOM ready function anywhere. Make sure you write up your script there so that you see no anomalies.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
      $("#new-nav").load("/php/grab.php" , function() {
           $('.main_title_news_submain_block').remove(); 
       });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: You also not using ready function in your example p.s. not working

Comment: $(function() {  is the alias for $(document).ready(function(){